# CSS Animation - All rotating words show on initial page load

Tags: html, css

I have played with this for hours and I can not seem to figure out why when the page initially loads, all the words show ..... then it starts rotating like normal. Can someone please help me to figure this out?

***EDIT*** --- It looks like the first and the last words load initially.

***EDIT*** --- I updated the snippet because I forgot the (6)th child. So now it does not put the first and last words on top of each other, but the timing is off a bit.

***EDIT*** --- Got it working buttery smooth! Updated the code snippet below to help anyone that may need it.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
h2{
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
 font-weight:400;
 font-size:35px;
 line-height:45px;
 color: #333;
 letter-spacing: -2px;
}
.text-center {
  text-align: center!important;
}
.rw-words-more {
  margin-left: 210px;
}
.rw-words {
  display: inline;
}
.rw-words-1 span {
  animation: rotateWord 18s linear infinite 0s;
  -ms-animation: rotateWord 18s linear infinite 0s;
  -webkit-animation: rotateWord 18s linear infinite 0s;
  color: #00abe9;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  padding-right: 2px;
  text-align: right;
}
.rw-words-1 span:nth-child(2){
  animation-delay: 3s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
}
.rw-words-1 span:nth-child(3){
  animation-delay: 6s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
}
.rw-words-1 span:nth-child(4){
  animation-delay: 9s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 9s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 9s;
}
.rw-words-1 span:nth-child(5){
  animation-delay: 12s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
}
.rw-words-1 span:nth-child(6){
  animation-delay: 15s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 15s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 15s;
}

/*topToBottom Animation*/
@keyframes rotateWord{
0%, 100%, 80% {
    opacity: 0;
}
2% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
    transform: translateY(-30px);
}
17%, 5% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
}
20% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(30px);
    transform: translateY(30px);
}
}
/*END*/
```

```html
<h2 class="text-center hidden-sm hidden-xs">
<span class="rw-words rw-words-1">
<span>Experience</span>
<span>Dedication</span>
<span>Knowledge</span>
<span>Perception</span>
<span>Innovation</span>
<span>Customers</span>
</span>
<span class="rw-words-more">Matters, that's why we've been <strong>in business for 10+ years!</strong></span>
</h2>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not accounting for 6 words. Change the first block to:

```
.rw-words-1 span {
  animation: rotateWord 15s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: rotateWord 15s linear infinite 0s;
    -webkit-animation: rotateWord 15s linear infinite 0s;
  color: #00abe9;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  padding-right: 2px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

Add:

```
.rw-words-1 span:nth-child(6){
    animation-delay: 12.5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 12.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 12.5s;
}
```

Comment: I must have been blind. Forgot the last child(6), I updated the code snippet above, but when you click the Run Code Snippet the animation seems off now. Guess I'll have to play with the timing. Thanks.